# Migrating to Cloud SaaS while keeping user data On-Premise AD

Tags: active-directory, cloud, office365, saas

We are in the planning/brainstorming phase of considering migrating to Cloud.

We came to an initial conclusion that we don't want a full-cloud solution. We think "initially" it's in our best interest to use Exchange, Lync and SharePoint as SaaS applications while keeping "all or most" of our user data on-premise.

Question: Is this option even possible? If so, recommended in terms of maintenance for example?

Edit: By searching on the Internet, all what we can find is either Only-Cloud or Hybrid authentication. But no one talks about user data on-premise.

Answer (score 0):

No. Office365 would have to be in Hybrid. Keeping all user data on-prem would be the most inefficient way of doing it, which is why MS won’t support it. It also defeats the point.